# Type '(instance: HTMLVideoElement | null) => void' is not assignable to type '(instance: HTMLDivElement | null) => void'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am using react with typescript. In my project, I am using forwardRef on div element, Here I am getting an error on div tag:

Type '(instance: HTMLVideoElement | null) => void' is not assignable to type '(instance: HTMLDivElement | null) => void'.

Here is my code:

```
type CanvasChilds = HTMLProps<HTMLDivElement>

const Canvas = forwardRef<HTMLVideoElement, CanvasChilds>(({childs}, ref) => (
  <div className='canvas' ref={ref}>
      { childs }
  </div>
));

export default Canvas;
```

Parent Component:

```
const pRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

return <div ref={pRef}>

</div>
```

Comment: Could you also share the snippet where the ref is passed from (Parent component)?

Comment: @SubratoPattanaik I updated the question and added parrent code

Comment: `forwardRef<HTMLDivElement, CanvasChilds>(({childs}, ref)` Why did you add `HTMLVideoElement`? It should be `HTMLDivElement`.

Comment: You need to change HTMLVideoElement to HTMLDivElement in forwardRef, also change 'childs' to 'children'